# How to create a big table with several columns with random values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, testing

I need to test different GUI tools for MySQL. For that I need database which contains big tables. I tried it using stored procedures but the thing is that the values in the different fields are same across all the rows. What I need is that the values should be random. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are many MySQL built in mathematical functions that you can use to generate random data. For example in your stored procedure you can add these SQL statements to generate random data and then insert them into the their respective field in the table. MySQL CONV() converts a number from one numeric base number system to another numeric base number system. After the conversion the function returns a string representation of the number. Syntax for which is: CONV(num, from_base, to_base)

```
select conv(floor(rand() * 99999999999999), 10, 24);
```

A sample stored procedure which generates 5 random strings and inserts it into the student table would look somewhat like this:

```
delimiter $$  
  create procedure randomizer()
    begin
      declare i int Default 0 ;
      declare random char(20) ;
      myloop: loop
      set random=conv(floor(rand() * 99999999999999), 10, 24) ;
      insert into `student` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (i+1,random) ;
      set i=i+1;
      if i=5 then
        leave myloop;
    end if;
    end loop myloop;
  end $$
  delimiter ;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was testing the Data Sync tool in [SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog). Would this randomiser procedure work in that.?

Comment: Yes. In fact you can write this stored procedure in the SQLyog's gui and enable the Data Sync tool. But I would suggest not to set the interval too short for Data Sync acquires row level locks in InnoDB and table level locks in MyISAM.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way can be you write sa java app for instance. it's so easy to create some loops to generate tons of fields and data .

Comment: Is there no way it can be done in Mysql without using Java app?

Comment: I think development procedures more hard than coding in Java , php, etc.

Comment: Maybe, But I find it easier.. Thanks anyways..:)